# Square export bug with toSVG();

Tags: javascript, svg, fabricjs

I draw a simple square and toSVG() return the next code:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" standalone="no" ?><!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC 
>  "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
> <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
>      xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" 
>      width="800" height="266.6666666666667" 
>      style="background-color: #FFFFFF" xml:space="preserve">
>   <desc>Created with Fabric.js 1.2.9</desc>
>   <defs></defs>
>   <rect x="-30" y="-30" rx="0" ry="0" width="60" height="60" 
>         style="stroke: #000000; stroke-width: 3; stroke-dasharray: ; 
>                stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; 
>                stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: none; opacity: 1;" 
>         transform="translate(400 133.33)"/>
> </svg>
> ```

I save that code as a image.svg and open it with corel draw and the result is:
http://s2.subirimagenes.com/imagen/previo/thump_8594256error.png

**The result isn´t a square, what is wrong?**

Comment: Maybe the missing value for `stroke-dasharray` confuses corel draw somehow?

Comment: No, I gave a value for the property I've even tried to remove it and the result is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that corel draw does not interpret well the code, with illustrator works perfectly.